# How do you debug Apple Watch OS 2.0 Apps?

Tags: xcode7, watchkit, watchos-2

I have been running a blank app template app on Watch OS 2.0 and put debug break points in the interfaceController and it appears that it is not working ?

Comment: It says it has finished running the apps and nothing happens....

Comment: Did you set the Xcode to debug the watch app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the correct scheme. Otherwise you are debugging the container app.

[image]